# What is the principle behind electric hoists having two load capacities?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

Electric hoists such as this one http://www.builderauthority.com/product/6013242/ commonly have two load capacities depending on whether a single-line or double-line configuration is used. What is it about the double-line configuration that allows the load capacity to be doubled?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The principle of the lever. Also applies when pulleys are used to multiply forces.

Comment: of course its spec'd like that because they have actually included the pulley in the package ( Or maybe they included the pulley so they can advertise twice the actual winch capacity.. )

Answer (score 2):

> What is it about the double-line configuration that allows the load capacity to be doubled?

Because the lifting force is literally split between 2 cables. One to the static anchor and one to the hoist's winch.

[image]
(image source: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Pulley1.svg))